# Imported files from prebuild script is not showing in Vercel deployment

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a Next.js app (v14) using the app directory. I'm using a node script to fetch all mdx files from another repository with the command `pnpm fetch-docs`.

This command is putting all content into `/content/docs` at the root of my project so I end up having:

- /app
- /components
- /content
  -- /docs
- lib
  ...

All the mdx files imported are not saved in the repo. I would like to fetch then at build time just before the `next build`. Locally I do first `pnpm fetch-docs` to fetch the data and then I launch `pnpm dev`. This is working really well.

The problem is when I am publishing my site to Vercel. I modified the build command to have `pnpm fetch-docs && next build` and I can see in the build process that it is fetching the data but if I see the source, I don't see the imported files and my app is missing those files.

Any idea where I might do something wrong?